# Summing values with similar row values

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a pandas data set that looks like this

```
city    difference 
NY       6
SF       8
LA       8
NY       9
SF       10
```

I want to sum up the values of the `difference` column based on the `city` column so that my final data set looks like

```
city    difference    total difference
NY       6              15
NY       9
LA       8               8
SF       10             10
```

I tried

```
df['total difference'] = df.groupby('city')['difference'].sum()
```

but it didn't work. I even tried [How to sum values of particular rows in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327613/how-to-sum-values-of-particular-rows-in-pandas) but got `NaN` values for the new column. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['total difference'] = df.groupby('city')['difference'].transform(sum) 
print (df)
  city  difference  total difference
0   NY           6                15
1   SF           8                18
2   LA           8                 8
3   NY           9                15
4   SF          10                18
```

And if need sort column also:

```
df['total difference'] = df.groupby('city')['difference'].transform('sum') 
df = df.sort_values('city')
print (df)
  city  difference  total difference
2   LA           8                 8
0   NY           6                15
3   NY           9                15
1   SF           8                18
4   SF          10                18
```

I was interested about differences in functions and timings are very similar:

```
#[10000000 rows x 2 columns]
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(10000000,2)), columns=['city','difference'])
#print (df)

In [293]: %timeit (df.groupby('city')['difference'].transform('sum'))
1 loop, best of 3: 570 ms per loop

In [294]: %timeit (df.groupby('city')['difference'].transform(sum))
1 loop, best of 3: 567 ms per loop

In [295]: %timeit (df.groupby('city')['difference'].transform(np.sum))
1 loop, best of 3: 561 ms per loop
```

Comment: That worked like magic! just a note, you added ' ' to the sum keyword by mistake! Thank you so much :)

Comment: `'sum'` should also work. There are number of internal functions that you can refer to by name vs. using builtin functions, e.g. `'sum'`, `'min'`, etc.

Comment: @jezrael personally, I would leave it as `'sum'`, this is generally accepted, it internally maps to `np.sum` without having to `import numpy as np` into your namespace.

Comment: @AChampion - I agree, I was doing timings some months ago and `'sum'` was faster as `sum`. Thanks for a comment. But I think it depends of real data, size of groups, ... And I think if use `'sum'` cal pandas sum function, but I am not sure what call in `sum`.

Comment: @AChampion thank you for making it clear that 'sum' would work as well!